# "Uncaught ReferenceError: enter is not defined" in JavaScript/Chrome

Tags: javascript, html

I just started studying JavaScript at school and I have a little project, a simple calculator.

I have a problem when I click on a button (5, 9, - etc), the chrome's inspector says:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: enter is not defined
>                  at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (calculatrice.html:34)

The JS is not finished.

```js
var DEBUT =0;
var ERREUR =1;
var OP1  =2;
var OP2  =3;
var FIN  =4;
var etat =DEBUT;
var op1  ='';
var op2  ='';
var op  = undefined;

function isdigit (bval){
 if((bval=='0')||(bval=='1')||(bval=='2')||(bval=='3')||(bval=='4')||(bval=='5')||(bval=='6')||(bval=='7')||(bval=='8')||(bval=='9')){
  return true;
 }
 return false;
}

function machine(bval) {
 if(etat==DEBUT){
  if((bval=='c')||(bval=='=')) return;
   
  if((bval=='+')||(bval=='-')||(bval=='/')||(bval=='*')){
   etat=ERROR;
  }
  if(isdigit(bval) == true) {
   etat=OP1;
   op1 += bval;
  }
 }
 
 if(etat==ERROR){
  if ((bval)=='C'){
   etat=DEBUT;
   op1="";
   op2="";
   op=undefined
  }
 }
 
 if (etat==OP1){
  if(bval=='c'){
   etat=DEBUT;
   valeur="";
   op1=undefined;
   op2=undefined;
  }
  if(bval=='='){
   etat=FIN;
   re.value += OPL;
  }
  
 if (etat=FIN){
  
 }
  
}

function enter (bval) {
 var re = document.getElementById("result");
 machine (bval);
 if (etat == DEBUT){
  re.value='';
 }
 else if (etat == ERREUR){
  re.value='ERREUR';
 } 
 else {
  re.value += bval;
```

```css
body{
 font-family  :Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size  :12pt;
 text-align  :center;
 background-color:#ffffff;
 color   :#777777;
 }
 
.box{
 margin   :0px auto;
 padding   :20px 20px 20px 20px;
 width   :600px;
 background-color:rgba(50,50,50,0.5 );
 text-align  :left;
 }
 
#result{
 margin   :20px auto;
 padding   :0px;
 display   :block;
 width   :100%;
 background-color:#ffffff;
 color   :#444444;
 border   :none;
 text-align  :right;
 font-size  :16pt;
 }
 
button{
 display   :block;
 width   :2em;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

 <head>
  <title>Calculatrice</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="calculatrice.css"/>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="calculatrice.js">
  </script>
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <div class="box">
   <input id="result" type="text" disabled="1"/>
  </div>
  <p/>
  <div class="box">
   <table>
    <tr>
     <td><button onclick ="enter('7');">7</button></td>
     <td><button onclick ="enter('8');">8</button></td>
     <td><button onclick ="enter('9');">9</button></td>
     <td><button onclick ="enter('/');">/</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td><button onclick ="enter('4');">4</button></td>
     <td><button onclick ="enter('5');">5</button></td>
     <td><button onclick ="enter('6');">6</button></td>
     <td><button onclick ="enter('*');">*</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td><button onclick ="enter('1');">1</button></td>
     <td><button onclick ="enter('2');">2</button></td>
     <td><button onclick ="enter('3');">3</button></td>
     <td><button onclick ="enter('+');">+</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td><button onclick ="enter('0');">0</button></td>
     <td><button onclick ="enter('.');">.</button></td>
     <td><button onclick ="enter('=');">=</button></td>
     <td><button onclick ="enter('-');">-</button></td>
     <td><button onclick ="enter('C');">C</button></td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: its most probably due to the wrong curly braces usage. Check if the enter function got nested inside some other function. You also have an undefined variable ERROR in your code which should be ERREUR i guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed some `curly braces`, plus `ERROR is undefined` and instead of onclick make use of `onClick` . Also the dom element `re` is undefined in `function machine` so either pass it of initialize it in the function.

```js
var DEBUT =0;
var ERROR =1;
var OP1  =2;
var OP2  =3;
var FIN  =4;
var etat =DEBUT;
var op1  ='';
var op2  ='';
var op  = undefined;

function isdigit (bval){
 if((bval=='0')||(bval=='1')||(bval=='2')||(bval=='3')||(bval=='4')||(bval=='5')||(bval=='6')||(bval=='7')||(bval=='8')||(bval=='9')){
  return true;
 }
 return false;
}

function machine(bval, re) {
 if(etat==DEBUT){
  if((bval=='c')||(bval=='=')) return;
   
  if((bval=='+')||(bval=='-')||(bval=='/')||(bval=='*')){
   etat=ERROR;
  }
  if(isdigit(bval) == true) {
   etat=OP1;
   op1 += bval;
  }
 }
 
 if(etat==ERROR){
  if ((bval)=='C'){
   etat=DEBUT;
   op1="";
   op2="";
   op=undefined
  }
 }
 
 if (etat==OP1){
  if(bval=='c'){
   etat=DEBUT;
   valeur="";
   op1=undefined;
   op2=undefined;
  }
  if(bval=='='){
   etat=FIN;
   re.value += OPL;
  }
 }
 if (etat=FIN){
  
 }
  
}

function enter (bval) {
 var re = document.getElementById("result");
 machine (bval, re);
 if (etat == DEBUT){
  re.value='';
 }
 else if (etat == ERROR){
  re.value='ERROR';
 } 
 else {
  re.value += bval; 
    }
}
```

```css
body{
 font-family  :Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size  :12pt;
 text-align  :center;
 background-color:#ffffff;
 color   :#777777;
 }
 
.box{
 margin   :0px auto;
 padding   :20px 20px 20px 20px;
 width   :600px;
 background-color:rgba(50,50,50,0.5 );
 text-align  :left;
 }
 
#result{
 margin   :20px auto;
 padding   :0px;
 display   :block;
 width   :100%;
 background-color:#ffffff;
 color   :#444444;
 border   :none;
 text-align  :right;
 font-size  :16pt;
 }
 
button{
 display   :block;
 width   :2em;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

 <head>
  <title>Calculatrice</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="calculatrice.css"/>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="calculatrice.js">
  </script>
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <div class="box">
   <input id="result" type="text" disabled="1"/>
  </div>
  <p/>
  <div class="box">
   <table>
    <tr>
     <td><button onClick ="enter('7');">7</button></td>
     <td><button onClick ="enter('8');">8</button></td>
     <td><button onClick ="enter('9');">9</button></td>
     <td><button onClick ="enter('/');">/</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td><button onClick ="enter('4');">4</button></td>
     <td><button onClick ="enter('5');">5</button></td>
     <td><button onClick ="enter('6');">6</button></td>
     <td><button onClick ="enter('*');">*</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td><button onClick ="enter('1');">1</button></td>
     <td><button onClick ="enter('2');">2</button></td>
     <td><button onClick ="enter('3');">3</button></td>
     <td><button onClick ="enter('+');">+</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td><button onClick ="enter('0');">0</button></td>
     <td><button onClick ="enter('.');">.</button></td>
     <td><button onClick ="enter('=');">=</button></td>
     <td><button onClick ="enter('-');">-</button></td>
     <td><button onClick ="enter('C');">C</button></td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Happy to help  :)

Comment: sorry to ask but do you have a little time to explain me how to do with the sign +-*/ in my calculator? I mean when it's OP1, if (bval='+-*/') what happen? what is the etat (state)?

Comment: What does OP1stand for, it will require me some effort to understand your logic.it will be better if you can ask it to some of your fellow mates. They may help.you better

Comment: it's the logic of my teacher... OP1 is, for exemple, 35 in the followed operation: 35-12

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some curly braces and `ERROR` is undefined (did you mean ERREUR?):

```
function machine (bval) {
    if(etat==DEBUT){
        if((bval=='c')||(bval=='=')) return;

        if((bval=='+')||(bval=='-')||(bval=='/')||(bval=='*')){
            etat=ERREUR; //previous ERROR was undefined, assuming you meant ERREUR
        }
        if(isdigit(bval) == true) {
            etat=OP1;
            op1 += bval;
        }
    }

    if(etat==ERREUR){ //previous ERROR was undefined, assuming you meant ERREUR
        if ((bval)=='C'){
            etat=DEBUT;
            op1="";
            op2="";
            op=undefined
        }
    }

    if (etat==OP1){
        if(bval=='c'){
            etat=DEBUT;
            valeur="";
            op1=undefined;
            op2=undefined;
        }
        if(bval=='='){
            etat=FIN;
            re.value += OPL;
        }
    } //<<<<---------------------- missing brace

    if (etat=FIN){

    }

}

function enter (bval) {
    var re = document.getElementById("result");
    machine (bval);
    if (etat == DEBUT){
        re.value='';
    }
    else if (etat == ERREUR){
        re.value='ERREUR';
    }
    else {
        re.value += bval;
    } //<<<<---------------------- missing brace
} //<<<<---------------------- missing brace
```